# Can I use the DEC VT220 composite output to connect it to a TV?

Tags: terminal, dec, television

I have a DEC VT220 from 1986, it has a composite output.  Works great in all its max-19200Kbps monochrome glory.

The composite output plug is a BNC, and it looks like BNC-to-RCA composite jack cables are available.

There's a few YouTube videos of VT220 output from this connected a capture card.

So ... is the output close enough to black and white NTSC that I could connect it to a TV through something that converts NTSC to RF or a TV that has a composite input?

I'm sure the 132 column mode will be horribly unreadable on an analog TV, but just wondering if it's at all possible before I waste a few bucks on the cable.

I think the effective resolution of this is 640x200 but am having trouble finding this information from old documentation.

---

Update:

Yep, it worked great.  Doesn't look half bad for the type of TV it is either, even though the image isn't centered.

[image: VT220 connected to a cheap 5 inch B&W TV with composite input]
[image: 132 column mode closeup]

Comment: The VT220 Tech Manual says: *BNC connector for composite video output to an optional
slave monitor. 
NOTE
The composite video output is an
RS170-like output; however, the use of
dc coupling is not in strict agreement with RS170 specifications.*

Comment: Fond memories of VMS Pascal on these, off a VAX 11/780.

Comment: As far as a general rule of thumb for composite output and horizontal resolution, generally a colour TV will be okay for up to 60 column text, an actual black and white TV will display 80 column text readily.  An actual monochrome monitor with a composite input may be able to do 132 column text with sufficient clarity to be usable, assuming a reasonably good dot pitch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This information is based on information from the [*DEC VT220
Technical Manual*](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_decterminaT220TechnicalManualNov84_11727585). I've not actually tried this out myself, but it [did work for the OP](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/can-i-use-the-dec-vt220-composite-output-to-connect-it-to-a-tv/12518#comment47125_12518) when he tried it.

**TLDR:** Yes, it's likely to work, and quite cheap to try using a
sub-$1 BNC to RCA adapter if you already have an RCA-RCA video cable.

Section 1.4 says that the "BNC connector for composite video output to
an optional slave monitor" uses "[RS170](http://www.epanorama.net/documents/video/rs170.html)-like" output, which is the
NTSC black-and-white television standard. Thus, the signal timing and
format should be compatible, as far as that goes.

There are three issues that might cause problems, most likely some
degradation of the display.

1. There's not general agreement on the voltage levels of RS-170;
   signals range from [0.7 V peak-to-peak](http://www.interfacebus.com/RS170_Video_Interface.html) or even less
   up to the 1.4 V peak-to-peak of the original standard. Given that
   your system is monochrome or will have only a couple of shades of
   grey, whatever voltage range VT-200 uses is unlikely likely to be
   an issue.
2. There's a warning in in that section of the manual: "the use of dc
   coupling is not in strict agreement with RS170 specifications." I
   don't think that this would be an issue either since it's only the
   AC signal that carries the information; input issues might also be
   fixed with a simple coupling capacitor.
3. As you pointed out, horizontal resolution may be an issue. As far
   as horizontal lines are concerned this is purely an analogue
   signal, so no harm can come from the TV not having enough
   horizontal bandwidth to display well the full horizontal resolution
   the monitor is using, but even 80-column text may be difficult to
   read. Since this will vary for each television or monitor, the only
   way to find out how good or bad it is is to test it with your
   particular TV.

Rather than buying a whole cable there are BNC to RCA adapters are
available for less than a dollar from many sources. If you already own
an RCA-RCA video cable, sourcing one of these is likely to be cheaper.
(Note that your RCA-RCA cable must be a coaxial cable for *video*;
using a non-coaxial audio RCA-RCA cable is likely to hugely degrade
the signal quality.)

[image: BNC plug to RCA jack adapater]

Comment: It's likely the monitor's input is AC coupled anyway.

Comment: I got a BNC to RCA adapter and it totally worked.

Comment: @Rodney: I think both video sources and displays are supposed to be capacitively coupled, but a display which is designed to work with a source that has a particular known DC bias can be simpler than one which would work with an AC-coupled source.